# find and terminate all active sessions by user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-cookies

I'm using cookie based sessions on a Rails 6 app with the following setup:

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :marshal
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 14.days
```

After a user changes his password I'd like to terminate all his active sessions, which could be in other browsers and/or devices. Something like this:

```
ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore.where(user_id: session[:user_id]).destroy_all
```

Only those aren't really valid methods for `CookieStore`. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot accomplish this via sessions no matter the way of session storage.

To be able to do this, you have to keep the list of active logins on the server in separate DB table and delete those records instead eg:

You create new table eg `logins` with columns `user_id` and `token`. Every time user logs in, you will create new record in this table and then you save `user_id` and `token` to the session:

```rb
def login
  # ...
  # user authorization code
  # ...

  login = user.logins.create(token: SecureRandom.uuid)
  session[:user_id] = login.user_id
  session[:user_token] = login.token
end
```

and every time you are loading user from the session you have to do two steps:

1. find user by ID
2. check `user_token` validity

```
def authorized_user
  @authorized_user ||= begin
    login = Login.find_by(user_id: session[:user_id], token: session[:user_token])
    return if login.blank?
    
    login.user
  end
end
```

And now, every time you want to logout user you just have to remove corresponding record from logins table.

In your case you want to logout user from all other devices, only thing you need to do is to execute following code:

```rb
authorized_user.logins.where.not(token: session[:user_token]).delete_all
```

and you are done.

Of course this is just a simple example, you also can hash or encrypt tokens, so they are not directly readable or you can add expiration date and automatically log out users when the date is exceeded, etc..